# Different style of opening popup window

Tags: javascript, html

I display a popup window in a simple format. I want to apply different format of opening popup a window. How can I apply format or style so that it looks very good when pop window opens? The following is my source code:

```
<div onMouseOver="show('healing')" onMouseOut="hide('healing')">
    <div id="healing" class="bgdiv" >
        <div id ="title" class="Title" >Healing</div>
        <img class="img"  src="images/healing.bmp">
        <div class="description" >Welcome Sir.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript code

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function show(id) 
{     
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible"; 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Have a look at jQuery ui dialog

Comment: Still problems, when yes how can we help?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at JQuery (http://jquery.com/). JQuery is a Javascript framework and you can use effects for displaying elements like fade, slide, show/hide.

All you have to do is change your code a little bit (Jquery solution):

```
<div id="showhealing">
    <div id="healing" class="bgdiv">
        <div id ="title" class="Title" >Healing</div>
        <img class="img" src="images/healing.bmp">
        <div class="description" > Welcome Sir.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#showhealing').hover(
        function() { $('#healing').show(500) }, function() { $('#healing').hide(500) }
    );
</script>
```

When you use JQuery UI, too (it's a extension for JQuery) you have much more effects. (Take a look here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/).

To use the Effects of JQuery UI you need to update your script like this:

```
<script>
    $('#showhealing').hover(
        function() { $('#healing').show("explode", {}, 500); }, function() { $('#healing').hide("explode", {}, 500) }
    );;
</script>
```

Comment: its not working please write in format so that i can understand

Comment: Did you have added JQuery to your file? Add this to your <head> of your html file: `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>` just use your directory.